# DB Connection issue only some times

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have a problem with the below code,There's no any coding error BUT sometimes it throws some exceptions.I just wanted to know any code organizing issue ? & how to fix it.

Sometimes it shows those exceptions

> 1.ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
>
> 2.Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed.

But Sometimes it works without any issue,as expected

My Coding Goes here

```
 [WebMethod, ScriptMethod]
public static List<HomeImageSliders> GetHomeImageSliders()
{
    List<HomeImageSliders> HomeImageList = new List<HomeImageSliders>();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comHomeImage = new SqlCommand("SP_GetHomeImageSliders", conDB);
        comHomeImage.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (conDB.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conDB.Open();
        }
           
        SqlDataReader rdr = comHomeImage.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      
            dt.Load(rdr);
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                HomeImageList.Add(new HomeImageSliders
                {
                    Id = (int)r["Id"],
                    ImagePath = r["ImagePath"].ToString(),
                    ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(r["ModifiedDate"]).Date

                });
            }

    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        conDB.Close();
    }
    return HomeImageList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "using" construction:

```
(using ommand comHomeImage = new SqlCommand("SP_GetHomeImageSliders", conDB) {
    (using SqlDataReader rdr = new SqlDataReader) {
        //do some things
    }

}
```

Comment: You should count your parentheses.  Also, SqlDataReader `has no constructors defined`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your connection sometimes is closed when you call

```
ExecuteReader()
```

But why don't you use a using block instead like this:

```
using(SqlConnection conDB = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 ...
}
```

this will close your connection to the DB when it loses scope.

Answer (score 1):

try to prevent using the same connection with two or more threads by usinglock

```
lock(_conDb)
{
    //// your code here
}
```

and also wrap your conDb in using block as below

```
using(SqlConnection conDB = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
 ...
}
```